# Where should I put the railing post in my deck design?

Tags: deck, railing, blocking

I'm in the process of building a deck.  Frame/rim joists are now complete, and I'm working on the blocking for the picture frame and screw-in aluminum posts.

I am planning on picture framing the steps as well...  but wondering how to block them.  Is there any more efficient way to do it than I currently am picturing in my head?  I see myself just adding *4* separate blocks

This is how the zoomed out look is...

[image]

Magenta are my added blocking between the blue stringers.

[image]

And finally.. I have 7 steps, plus the deck (so, count it as 8).  Where do you suggest putting the middle post?  There is obviously one stuck at the front of the step on step 1 (bottom) and step 8 (deck).  Due to supply, I had to get (2) 6' railings for this, and not one 8'.

Would you suggest putting it in the center of the railing?  They are long, and will be cut down to size.  (This would have it be near the "back" of that step).

- Pro - Equal railing length.
- Con - the perceived "height" of the railing is not the same along all railings

[image]

Or, would you put it at the "front" of step 4 or 5.  This would make the "height" the same for all railings, but the distance between the sets of railings would be different.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Akshue - possibly depends on where your brooker rod goes?  And presumably the post goes outside the stringers?

Comment: in your post diagram where is the ground?

Comment: You appears to be going for a stringers under the treads design, is that correct? how is the bottom of the stringer fixed to the ground?

Comment: Do you stairs have risers?

Comment: Ground is 7” below step 1.  Stringers are attached to a proper footing, below the frost line.  Stairs do have solid risers.

Answer (score 1):

What I did... Lots of finniky cuts that I do one at a time, but not too bad.

The tiny short pieces of scrap on the left and the right are likely NOT needed, but I decided to include them on the stairs that hold posts (I have screw-in posts) to help cut down whatever "wiggle" is in the screw that lands in between the two supports.

[image]

Obviously, the stringers in the middle have nothing special - they will only see straight boards without corners.

Answer (score 0):

just use a single plank under each tread . eg: some of your joist timber laid flat.

Be sure to have enough toe space to meet your building code, the rules are often relaxed for outdoor stairs.

If you really want to go with blocking try a V shaped layout, (with a  back and a diagonal, such short blocking can be 2x4 laid flat (instead of doubled) if you need more width

Comment: Wouldn’t this cause concern over draining?  I worry that this would hold onto water too much.  Also, my posts are top-secured, and looking for 5” of meat to screw into.

Comment: possibly, but you always get that.  you could maybe seal unde the floor boards with a flexible urethane sealant/adhesive.